# Schwartz Inequality (probability) - first step in proof

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand the Schwartz Inequality for random variables, which states
$$(E[XY])^2 \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2] $$

The solution states that we can assume $E[Y^2] \neq 0$ because if this were the case than we would have $Y=0$, which would make the inequality trivially true. Interestingly, the text does not make any statement on $E[X^2]$. Can I assume the that $X$ follows the same reasoning as $Y$?

Using the statement above, the book asserts as the first step of the proof
$$ 0 \leq E[ (X - \frac{E[XY]}{E[Y^2]}Y)^2] $$

Could someone provide some intuition as to how the first step is derived? The rest of the proof is trivial.

Thanks.

Comment: That step is done precisely so that we get a quadratic involving expectations - and quadratic inequalities can be studied using only the coefficients, so we get something natural to study.

Comment: This is an inequality of *Schwarz* without $t$.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value of a positive random variable is always $ \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may make the same argument for $X$, although it is not needed in the proof (only $E[Y^2]$ is in the denominator).

The first step of the proof is not really deduced from anything; it is "pulled out of the air" and gives us what we want. However, this technique of looking at a quadratic appears in proofs of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in other contexts.